# Known HTTP Headers with Invalid Context

Tags: http, parsing, error-handling, http-headers

### Headers May Be Unknown

The HTTP specification is very explicit in the principal that unknown headers may be safely ignored by a message recipient.

This is cautioned by the requirement that clients and servers must implement all headers specified by the version of HTTP to which they declare conformance; i.e. a server declaring HTTP/1.1 capabilities must not ignore valid HTTP/1.1 headers since this would mean it was falsely advertising its capabilities and clients would receive unexpected responses.

This principal is simple and eminently practical; it allows new headers to be added that will refine the response from servers that understand them whilst allowing servers that do not understand them to still provide a response likely to be of use to the client.

### Headers May Be Recognised with Invalid Context

The point that I cannot seem to clarify by reading the specification is how to handle headers that are known and supported by the server but that have been incorrectly used by the client.

#### Response Headers in Request Messages

For example, the `Server:`, `Retry-After:`, `Location:`, etc. headers are all strictly response headers. For these headers to be received as part of a request would, then, seem to indicate some serious misunderstanding between the client and the server.

#### Request Headers in Response Messages

Similarly, conditional headers such as `If-None-Match:` and `If-Modified-Since:`, the `Host:` header, and `Accept:`, `Accept-Charset:` headers are all strictly request headers; their presence in a response would likewise seem to indicate that the sender is committing protocol errors.

#### Entity Headers in Message Without Payload

Lastly, not all messages contain a payload so the presence of entity headers such as `content-language:` and `content-range:` would likewise seem to be in error.

### Question

Should known headers in an invalid context be treated as a protocol error? In practice this would require 4xx responses from Servers and would require that clients consider the response to be malformed.

Or, should such headers be ignored in the same manner as unknown headers?

#### Additional Notes

I was unable to find any discussions of this so I have tried to discover how existing web servers behave. Some fiddler requests to Google and Wikipedia seemed to indicate that they both:

- ignore response headers contained in requests
- ignore entity headers contained in requests that have no payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should known headers in an invalid context be treated as a protocol error?**

No. Not unless they make the request completely unintelligible or impossible to satisfy. If a malformed or out-of-place header can be ignored, then do so.

Here's a quote from RFC2616 (the HTTP/1.1 specification):

> #### 19.3 Tolerant Applications
>
> Although this document specifies the requirements for the generation of HTTP/1.1 messages, not all applications will be correct in their implementation. We therefore recommend that operational applications be tolerant of deviations whenever those deviations can be interpreted unambiguously.

Anyway, a response header in a request (and vice versa) should always be treated as an unknown header. There is no way you can be sure that a future version of HTTP won't permit them to be used in this way.

Comment: I've been reading the revised specification, which is why I missed the RFC2616 quote; thank you, it gives a very clear statement of the approach. The comparable quote in RFC7320 appears to be in section 2.5 and reads `Unless noted otherwise, a recipient MAY attempt to recover a usable protocol element from an invalid construct. HTTP does not define specific error handling mechanisms except when they have a direct impact on security...` which seems less explicit than the RFC2616 quote.